# How to access the session variable in the controller

Tags: session, symfony

I have created a session variable in one controller and I want to access it in another controller. In `loginsuccess` controller I set the session:

```
$session->set('id',$id);
```

How can I access this variable in another controller?

Answer (score 33):

There is `session` service which you should use:

```
$id = $this->get('session')->get('id');
```

or

```
$this->get('session')->set('id', $id);
```

Comment: I agree, that's a better way to go.

Comment: Gives me `Undefined method get`

Answer (score 17):

On a more general note, if your controller extends from the base Symfony controller (`Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller`) you can get the session in 3 ways:

1. `$session = $this->container->get('session');`
2. `$session = $this->get('session');` (which basically is a shortcut to 1)
3. `$session = $request->getSession();`

Answer (score 5):

While Cyprian answer is valid, you will find in the documentation the following usage:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

$session = new Session();
$session->start();

// set and get session attributes
$session->set('id',$id);
$session->get('id'); //this is the line you are looking for
```

http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/http_foundation/sessions.html

Note:

> While it is recommended to explicitly start a session, a sessions will
>   actually start on demand, that is, if any session request is made to
>   read/write session data.

Comment: Good point. But pay attention that this is the component documentation. Actually according to the framework docs there is a third way to play with session service: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#managing-the-session :)

Comment: but, maybe it's worth to add, the session object returned from Request object is exactly the same as the one from service container

Comment: Since the question is about accessing the session form a controller, your answer makes more sense. But as you said, probably worth to mention than `$this->getRequest()->getSession()` is valid as well in this context!

Answer (score 1):

There is a third way as writing in a comment :

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;

public function indexAction(SessionInterface $session)
{
     $session->set('test', 'yes !');
}
```

This way allows you to get type-hinted variable, this way you can access methods of the Session object in your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

**In a Symfony 6 controller:**

Add an argument to your action and type-hint it with `SessionInterface`. ([see doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#managing-the-session))

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;

class FooController
{
    public function index(SessionInterface $session): Response
    {
        $session->set('id', $id);

        ...
    }
}
```

**In a Symfony 6 service:**

Inject the `RequestStack` service to the constructor and get the session from it. ([see doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/session.html#basic-usage))

```
<?php

namespace App\Service;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class FooService
{
    public function __construct(private RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
    }

    public function bar()
    {
       $session = $this->requestStack->getSession();
       $session->set('id', $id);

       ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Symfony 6**

Since Symfony 6 session is now available only through the Request object and the RequestStack
see https://symfony.com/doc/current/session.html

So in your controller inject Request Object then from this request object you can now access the session with getSession method

```
//inside your controller

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

public function index(Request $request):Response
{
    $session = $request->getSession();
}
```

Hope this helps ( this is my first answer ) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Symfony 6.2+
Manually access
Set

```
$session = new Session();
$session->set('db_user', $site->getUser());
```

Get

```
$session = new Session();
dd($session->all());
```

Or You can access with RequestStack

```
/** @var RequestStack $request */
$request = $this->container->get(RequestStack::class);
if ($request->getCurrentRequest()?->hasSession()) {
    $session = $request->getCurrentRequest()->getSession();
}
```