# Call to a member function has() on null while tring to make a login function

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

[Click here /....This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImPIT.png)

while trying to make a login function an error occur Call to a member function has() on null ...................................................................................................................................................................................................if you helps me now. it will be a support for my career...hope i get the right answer.
.......................................................................................

### My Controller

```
 /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     */
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    $session = $request->getSession();
//    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();

    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $repository=$em->getRepository('AppBundle:User');
    if($request->getMethod()=='POST')
    {
        $session->clear();
        $username=$request->get('username');
        $password=$request->get('password');
        $remember=$request->get('remember');

        $user=$repository->findOneBy(array('userName'=>$username,'password'=>$password));
        if($user)
        {
            if($remember=='remember-me'){
        $login= new Login();
            $login->setUsername($username);
            $login->setPassword($password);
            $session->set('login',$login);
        }
            return $this->render('AppBundle:pro:homepage.html.twig',array('name'=>$user->getFirstName()));
        }
else {
return $this->render('AppBundle:pro:login.html.twig',array('name'=>'Login Error'));
}
    }
    else{
        if($session->has('login')){
            $login= $session->get('login');
            $username= $login->getUsername();
            $password= $login->getPassword();
            $user=$repository->findOneBy(array('userName'=>$username,'password'=>$password));
        if($user){
            return $this->render('AppBundle:pro:homepage.html.twig',array('name'=>$user->getFirstName()));
        }

        }
        return $this->render('AppBundle:pro:login.html.twig');
    }
}


}
```

### My Modal

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Modals;


class Login
{

    private $username;

    private $password;

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;


    }


    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }


    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;


    }

}
?>
```

### My Entity

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

/**
 * User
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $password;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get username
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get password
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace `$session->has('login')` with `isset($_SESSION['login'])` and make a try

Answer (score 0):

This error means **$session** is null.I don't know which version of Symfony you are using but , to access session within controller you can use

```
$this->get('session')
```

For more informations this is related to [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872729/how-to-access-the-session-variable-in-the-controller)

Hope this help.

Comment: im using symfony 3.4

Comment: why don't you use this symfony's feature https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security.html ? It seems to fit your need and it's more symfony's friendly.